# vue3 css :deep() selector not working with PrimeVue library

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I an working with vue3 and PrimeVue library. When I try to override css fields of PrimeView components using `:deep()` selector it just does not have any effect. only when I am using an unscoped style it applies my changes. I have trouble understanding why it does not work.

code for example with `:deep()`:

```js
<template>
    <Toast position='buttom-right'/>
</template>

<style scoped>
:deep(.p-toast-message-icon) {
    margin-right: 10px !important;
}
</style>
```

This doesn't work.

But when using `style` without scoped like so:

```js
<style>
.p-toast-message-icon {
    margin-right: 10px !important;
}
</style>
```

This does work.

Answer (score 1):

The rules generated by a `:deep` selector target children of the current component, but the `p-toast` is attached to the body, so the generated class will have no effect.

However, you can set [passthrough options](https://primevue.org/toast/#pt.demo) to pass the style rule to the icon:

```html
<Toast
    :pt="{
        icon: { style: 'marginRight: 10px !important;' }
    }"
/>
```

or

```html
<Toast
    :pt="{
        icon: { class: 'mr-2' }
    }"
/>
```

Here it is in a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/primevue-demo-forked-0ccb5u?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue%3A14%2C27)

Comment: Thank you I will try this. Although the Toast component was just one example, I also encountered this problem in almost every primevue component, do you know if there is a general solution? or I need to find a solution for each component?

Comment: Hmmm, the problem with the `:deep()` selector only affects components that are attached outside the current component. With other components, `:deep()` should work, as suggested by the  [documentation](https://primevue.org/theming/#scopedcss). Hard to say why it is not working without looking at it.

Comment: For some reason your answer still didn’t work, what could prevent it from applying the class even though I am using pass through?

Comment: Hmm, not sure, I have added a link to a Sandbox where you can see it working.

Comment: Thank you I will try to find my issue with it

Comment: If you can provide a sandbox, I am happy to take a look